# How does .ignoring fit into the Selenium Webdriver Fluent Waits process flow?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Say I have a fluent wait that has the following set:

```
.withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

I have drawn up the following process flow:
[image]

How does the `.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)` fit into this flow?

From my understanding, the test will look for the element and if not found, then it will search again at intervals set by the Polling Value. This will continue until the Timeout time is reached.

What happens though if the element is not found by the Timeout time but the error that is to be thrown is the error that is to be ignored?

I'm not sure how .ignoring exception fits into this process.

Comment: Let's say you have set Timeout t=60 second, p =10 second. Element is available at 59th second so there may be 5 NoSuchElementException thrown which will be ignored Take look at code https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/81fcbef376a443e730d178f1ad9bdcf998cd8d35/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java#L243

Comment: `Element not found exception` wouldn't terminate the process. The exception would be ignored and the next step would be `Execute test` if I understood your code correctly. The process will be terminated if the condition is not fulfilled within a given time frame OR not ignored exception is thrown